# advice needed for my UNION ALL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my table is

```
user: userID -  userLogo
content: userID - contentID  - contentImage
promo: promoID - userID - promoImage
```

this is my query

```sql
SELECT userID,userLogo FROM user
WHERE userID=4
UNION ALL
SELECT userID,contentImage FROM content
WHERE userID=4
UNION ALL
SELECT userID,promoImage FROM promo
WHERE userID=4
ORDER BY userID
```

and the result is

```
userID  userLogo
4      ../images/user/000004.jpg 
4      ../images/content/000003.jpg
4      ../images/content/000004.jpg
4      ../images/content/000005.jpg
4      ../images/content/000006.jpg
4      ../images/promo/000003.jpg
4      ../images/promo/000004.jpg
4      ../images/promo/000005.jpg
```

the result obtained is quite similar to what i want, but the column title is not what i want

and, about php.. is it possible to use the query above to unlink all  images in the result?

one more question, talk about efficiency, does my query impose heavy load to database? if yes, please give advices or any solution .

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Use `AS` to declare title (well enough for 1-st part in `UNION`). 2. Yes, it is possible. 3. Depends of data size & tables structure.

Comment: In general asking 3 questions in a single one is not a good idea especially in this case when they are related to different things. Better ask a separate question `is it possible to unlink images from php` The query itself and the database schema are scarcely relevant to that question.

Comment: noted, will not do it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third column so that you can check what type of image is with condition

```
SELECT 
    userID,
    userLogo,
    'userLogo' as Type 
FROM user 
WHERE userID=4

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    userID,
    contentImage,
    'contentImage' as Type 
    FROM content 
    WHERE userID=4

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    userID,
    promoImage,
    'promoImage' as Type 
FROM promo 
WHERE userID=4
ORDER BY userID
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When you use Union .... First Select Statements Column names will be the Results Table Column name... For get the specific column name you need to use AS operator like this

> ```
> "SELECT userID AS YOUR_CHOICE,userLogo AS 'your_choice' FROM user
> WHERE userID=4
> UNION ALL
> SELECT userID,contentImage FROM content
> WHERE userID=4
> UNION ALL
> SELECT userID,promoImage FROM promo
> WHERE userID=4
> ORDER BY userID"
> ```

1. Yes
2. If the table size is big, then it's not a good idea.. That time you can use JOIN..

Comment: when i use join, the userID is shown in distict value.. causing the query result not showing the full file path ...

Comment: file path depends on your script...not in query..so, run the query in appropriate script..BUT!!!! if path string less then the database path field size then you can increase the database path field size